# How to get only certain fields from JSON with retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, api, retrofit

I have a problem with Retrofit. I am working on an Android app which needs to get information about a product from Open Food Facts API. I tried with Retrofit, I created a class with the information I want from JSON (I only need a few fields and I didn't want to make a class with all the JSON fields, because there are over 50 I think)

```
public class Product {
    @SerializedName("product_name_en")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("brands")
    private String company;

    @SerializedName("update_key")
    private int key;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Then I created an interface with the @GET method and the relative URL to the API endpoint

```
public interface OpenFoodFactsAPI {

    @Headers("User-Agent: Fooducate - Android - Version 1.0")
    @GET("/api/v0/product/01223004")
    Call<Product> getProducts();
}
```

And inside my fragment I did this

```
TextView text = view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://us.openfoodfacts.org")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        OpenFoodFactsAPI jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(OpenFoodFactsAPI.class);
        Call<Product> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getProducts();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Product> call, Response<Product> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    text.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }

                Product product = response.body();
                    String content = "";
                    content += "NAME: " + product.getName() + "\n";
                    content += "COMPANY: " + product.getCompany() + "\n";
                    content += "KEY: " + product.getKey() + "\n";
                    text.append(content);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable t) {
                text.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

I tried the get request on a website and it works. However, in my app an empty response is returned.

You can view the JSON from the api [here](https://us.openfoodfacts.org/api/v0/product/01223004)

If you have any idea about this problem, please answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `API` you are not getting exactly the `Product` as response. You are getting another object which is `Product` is a child object.

You need to create a response Like below,

```
public class ResponseObject{
  @SerializedName("status")
  private int status;

  @SerializedName("status_verbose")
  private String status_verbose;

  @SerializedName("product")
  private Product product;

   //getters and setters goes here
}
```

then your `interface` should be like below as you are expecting `ResponseObject` here.

```
public interface OpenFoodFactsAPI {

@Headers("User-Agent: Fooducate - Android - Version 1.0")
@GET("/api/v0/product/01223004")
Call<ResponseObject> getProducts();
}
```

This will solve your problem. Update me If you have any problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

After using

```
public class ResponseObject{
@SerializedName("status")
private int status;

@SerializedName("status_verbose")
private String status_verbose;

@SerializedName("product")
private Product product;
}
```

Just change

```
public int getKey() {return key;}
```

to

```
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
```

Otherwise

```
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ecoscore20210127"
```

because in json it exists like  "update_key": "ecoscore20210127"

Comment: Yes, I noticed that as well. Thank you!